# Get labels of data with same color in scipy dendrogram

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I did a hierarchical clustering using `scipy` and following is my dendrogram. Now I need to get the labels of the leaves with particular color. For ex: I need to find the labels for red, blue, green etc. Any help on this?

```
B = dendrogram(linkage_matrix,
               color_threshold=250,
               labels=df.session.tolist(),
               distance_sort='ascending')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add least add some import statements?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to solve the exact same problem, but the answer above is not correct. Colors from color_list does not correspond to colors of the *leaves* but to colors of the *links* - the pi-shaped structures connecting clusters. Color_list and ivl doesn't even need to be the same length.

Here you can find a way to get the labels of the leaves:
http://nxn.se/post/90198924975/extract-cluster-elements-by-color-in-python

Answer (score -2):

B, or whatever is returned by the dendrogram function, is a dictionary with the following keys:

```
print B.keys()
['ivl', 'dcoord', 'leaves', 'color_list', 'icoord']
```

'color_list' will look something like this:

```
print B['color_list']
['g', 'g', 'b', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'b']
```

And 'ivl' will look like this:

```
print B['ivl']
['4', '1', '5', '6', '3', '2', '7', '0']
```

It just remains to do a list comprehension:

```
myInd = [i for i, c in zip(B['ivl'], B['color_list']) if c=='g']
print myInd
['4', '1']
```